# Formatting selectors in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I've got some python code in Altair to plot some data.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# Load data from the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('penis_sizes.csv')

# Define a dropdown menu for the Continent/Region column
continent_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=list(data['Continent/Region'].unique()))
continent_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Continent/Region'], bind=continent_dropdown, name='Continent/Region')

# Define a range slider for the Length of erect penis in inches column
length_slider = alt.binding_range(min=data['Length of erect penis in inches'].min(), max=data['Length of erect penis in inches'].max(), step=0.1)
length_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Length of erect penis in inches'], bind=length_slider, name='Length\ (inches)')

# Define a range slider for the Circumference of erect penis in inches column
circumference_slider = alt.binding_range(min=data['Circumference of erect penis in inches'].min(), max=data['Circumference of erect penis in inches'].max(), step=0.1)
circumference_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Circumference of erect penis in inches'], bind=circumference_slider, name='Circumference (inches)')

# Define the scatter plot with interactive filters
scatter = alt.Chart(data).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Length of erect penis in inches',
    y='Circumference of erect penis in inches',
    color=alt.Color('Continent/Region', legend=None),
    tooltip=['Country', 'Continent/Region', 'Length of erect penis in inches', 'Circumference of erect penis in inches']
).add_selection(
    continent_selection,
    length_selection,
    circumference_selection
).transform_filter(
    continent_selection
).transform_filter(
    length_selection
).transform_filter(
    circumference_selection
)

# Combine the scatter plot with the selection widgets
dashboard = alt.hconcat(
    scatter,
    data=data,
    title='Erect Penis Length and Circumference by Country and Continent/Region'
)

dashboard
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is customise the selectors so they are formatted properly. How do I do that?